# increasing the size of columns to fit into datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a datagridview in c# winforms and I am trying to make my columns autofit into my datagridview so that the datagridview doesn't have blank space on the left.

I am binding a dataset to my datagridview and was able to autosize the columns based on their content but able to make them fit into datagridview as I see blank space in my datagridview

```
 dgvData.DataSource = dsData.Tables[0];        
  dgvData.AutoResizeColumns();
 dgvData.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

**May I know a way to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Fill` instead of `AllCells`.

```
 dgvData.DataSource = dsData.Tables[0];        
 dgvData.AutoResizeColumns();

 dgvData.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```